# JQuery AJAX .load - flash chart doesnt load in IE

Tags: jquery, ajax, flash, internet-explorer, coldfusion

An IE issue has me completely stumped. I have a coldfusion page that uses JQuery's AJAX .load function to load in a new flash file that is generated by coldFusion's cfchart tag. This works completely fine in firefox: the new flash file and new html elements load. However in IE: all of the html elements that are geneated with the flash object are loaded, except the flash object and embed tags do not show up at all after running an ajax call in IE. After looking in Fiddler, the flash application type response data doesnt even show up for IE. It does however for Firefox.

I thought maybe it has to do with any kind of media, so i changed the chart type to output as a jpg file instead of flash. And it loads completely fine in IE. So something is preventing IE from receiving the flash response data.

Here's what i've done so far - and no luck so far:

- Added to the HTML header: `<META
  HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL"
  CONTENT="NO-CACHE"><META
  HTTP-EQUIV="EXPIRES" CONTENT="01 Jan
  1970 00:00:00 GMT"><META
  HTTP-EQUIV="PRAGMA"
  CONTENT="NO-CACHE">`
- Added random GET varaible name with a random value to call URL
- Changed the ajax method from GET to POST
- Changed the ajax retreival method to the .ajax with cache set to false.

Any suggestions or insight would be greatly appreciated. Thank you thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried specifying jQuery's `$.ajax` "cache" option to false? IE caches pretty aggressively (I've seen it cache .jsp files.), so I wonder if jQuery knows how to get around this natively.

Comment: No luck. The HTML elements that are generated with the flash file in the AJAX call, show up fine - just not the flash file... I even added random GET variables with random values, as i heard this might fix it but didnt work either.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, although I haven't investigated enough to be sure what it is, jQuery loads or even .show() will fail silently in IE when applied to a flash object.

There's a jQuery Plugin that makes it possible to dynamically load flash, though -- http://jquery.thewikies.com/swfobject/

It should work for this application.